# Easy Way To Detect Collisions With Window Edge In Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, game-development

I am making a non-scrolling platformer in pygame, and am wondering if there is an easy way to detect collisions with the edge of the window, without creating four rects offscreen. Does anyone know if there is? Thanks.

Comment: ```if x + width < left_edge and x > right_edge: return True``` Do this for y too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing collisions for Rects, you can use

```
if (Rect.left < 0 or Rect.right > (window width) or 
      Rect.top < 0 or Rect.bottom > (window height)):
    collision = True # do whatever collision code you need here
```

If you need a way to get the screen size, you can use

```
width, height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
```

and then use the `width` and `height` variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pygame.Rect.contains`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains) to test if a rectangle is entirely inside another rectangle:

```py
window_rect = screen.get_rect()
if not window_rect.contains(object_rec):
    # [...]
```

Use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to test if a rectangle is entirely outside another rectangle:

```py
window_rect = screen.get_rect()
if not window_rect.colliderect(object_rec):
    # [...]
```